# Print docx files as pdfs using PdfCreator

Tags: c#, printing

I am trying to print docx files as pdfs in a file using PDFCreator.The code does everything that I need but the printing window is shown.  I am trying to print without displaying the Pdf creator window.How can I do that and how can I specify the printing location?
I also don't want to use office automation because I will use the application on the server.

```
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo("C:\\Users\\Test1.docx");
info.Verb = "Print";
info.CreateNoWindow = true;
info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
Process.Start(info);
```

Comment: Does the above code work?

Comment: Yes but the Pdf creator window is showing up